# How to evaluate the Database size requirements for OBIEE 12c

Tags: architecture, oracle12c, obiee

Experts,

We are considering OBIEE12c implementation. How to evaluate what should be the Database size requirement for OBIEE 12c metadata( MDS and BIPLATFORM items)? is there a rule which we follow?

Details:
App: OBIEE 12c 
database: Oracle 12c

Oracle Official guidelines no mention any thing for Enterprise Edition however they 500MB DB size is sufficient for single user. However, nothing is mentioned about enterprise installation.

Any rule or calculation we follow for sizing the Database?

Comment: Did you give up on this question?

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for following up. We contacted Oracle and they implied the same. We finally decided to go with the existing size since the existing system is more than capable enough.
In a way, gave up on the calculation or a straight up formula.

Comment: Thanks for following up, Nik

Answer (score 0):

As always: It depends.

It depends on how many users and how much they do. How many Agents, how many Scorecards, how many annotations,  etc etc.

I never saw this run into issues as  even 500GB are a glorified USB stick.